# Does Bootstrap automatically add an active class to radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues with bootstrap radio buttons and I just wanted to quickly check if Bootstrap should be appending the active class to a set of radio buttons I have, because if it is supposed to then it isn't and I can figure out why.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="span12 btn-group pageSelector" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Settings</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Fields</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Layout</button>
</div>
```

And my JS

```
$('.pageSelector').button();
```

I am running with jQuery UI as well but have removed the button widget to avoid the conflict.

Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check it yourself with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tool or something.

But yes, once it's clicked it adds an active-class.

Comment: Hi, I did check with firebug on the bootstrap site and yes it does but mine it doesn't, I wasn't sure if it was an extra function or if it was part of the base functionality. I will continue to pull my hair out then. Thanks :-)

Comment: I got it, I loaded Jquery after bootsrap.. swapped that around it worked perfectly :-) DIR!! Thanks